# one menu item for two actions

Tags: android, menuitem, optionmenu

I have option menu configured and one of the items is used to enable a service in the background.

When the action takes place I am changing the item title from "Enable Service" to "Disable service" and setting a boolean value accordingly.

the issue starts when the app closes and then the class is reloaded. The boolean would be reset to the initial value.

What I would like to know is:

1. what is the best practice to use for having one item menu that does different actions based on it's status.
2. What is the best practice for keeping the boolean value in his last state? (shared preferences?)

Comment: Yes, you keep `boolean` in `preferences` and every time check the value and update it.

Comment: You should use Shared Prefs.

Comment: instead of a caption change button, use a switch "Awsome Service state ON/OFF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store primitive values then the best practice is use **shared preferences**, then when ever user close the app then you can store the value in shared preference then next time user open the app you can simply get value from shared preferences.

By using single menu item you can handle two actions "Enable Service" and "Disable service" based on value getting from shared preferences.

Comment: Thank you all, what I have end up doing is to indeed use shared pref to store the boolean value, one thing that was tricky is that when the class is reloaded the title configured in the menu xml file is loaded also and doesnt describe the real state. so I used onprepareoptionmenu to set the title based on the boolean value exists in the shared pref. hope that will help someone else'

Answer (score 0):

1.) Keep it at the same place with different icons/names at the same time being distinguishably related to each other. e.g. (On / Off) name/icon.

2.) Using shared prefs would be the way to go since you are only storing a primitive value. It's faster than using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like that
When you load your Activity..

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
static int currentAction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyAction", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getInt("Action", 0) == 0) {  //  0 for Enable Service
        // set menu as Enable
        currentAction = 0;
    } else {   //  1 for Disable service
        // set menu as Disable
        currentAction = 1;
    }

}
```

and when you click on menu Item then..

```
if (currentAction == 0) {
        //Do Action for Enable and change Action
        currentAction = 1;
    } else {
        //Do Action for Disable and change Action
        currentAction = 1;
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("Action", currentAction);
    editor.commit();
    }
```

Hope its help...!!